# How to make an SQL Query process faster using NOT IN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL Query:

```
SELECT sequence, ticketnumber FROM tickets t
WHERE t.ticketnumber NOT IN (SELECT ticketnumber FROM ticket_updates)
```

it is querying thousands of rows in both tables - how can i make it run a little faster? Is there an alternative?

Comment: These can give you better idea which method to choose [*LEFT JOIN / IS NULL vs. NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS: nullable columns*](http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=24888) ,[*NOT IN vs. NOT EXISTS vs. LEFT JOIN / IS NULL: MySQL*](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Comment: You could try a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of a sub-select, but I am not sure if it would be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT sequence, ticketnumber FROM tickets t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT u.ticketnumber FROM ticket_updates u WHERE u.ticketnumber = t.ticketnumber)
```

The `NOT EXISTS` query is optimized for this situation (just seeing if a row does/doesn't exist). It's not the only option and other queries will evaluate to the same operation, but this is what I would choose because its clear what is being asked.

Also, for this particular query (the `NOT EXISTS`), indexing `ticket_updates.ticketnumber` would also yield a performance increase since the lookup speed would probably go from `O(n)` to `O(log(n))` or `O(1)` (complete guess here...please correct me if I am utterly wrong).

Answer (score 3):

MySQL doesn't optimize this type of subquery well.  It will keep running the second SELECT for every row in the outer query.  Use a LEFT JOIN instead:

`SELECT sequence, ticketnumber
FROM tickets t
LEFT JOIN ticket_updates tu ON (tu.ticketnumber = t.ticketnumber)
WHERE tu.ticketnumber IS NULL;`